# ActiveCell.Value = Time vba without seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, time

I have a "timesheet" macro for clock in and clock out times for employees to use at work.  The macro I have is this:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
```

It works well and only displays as "7:30 AM", as an example, but in the edit field, there are seconds and this can make the shift time (formula =IF(OR(C2="",F2=""),"",((F2-C2)-(E2-D2))*24)) off by a minute if the seconds do not line up, but we do not pay off of seconds, just minutes.  Is there a way to modify the macro where only the hour and minute are captured.  Formatting does not correct it.  I am fine with it returning "7:30:00 AM" each time and not the actual seconds.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Round down to the nearest minute:

```
 ActiveCell.Value = Int(Time * 24 * 60) / (24 * 60)
```

Or

```
ActiveCell.Value = TimeSerial(Hour(Time),Minute(Time),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this also:*

```
ActiveCell.Value = Format(range("D2"), "HH:MM")
```

**Note,** Cell `D2` has formula calculating the Time you have show in the question above.

**Or** *in place of **ActiveCell** you may use the followings also:*

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm"
Range("E327").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
```